# jQuery when user clicks outside the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with input fields and a button which fades in when you focus in any field.

I would like to make the button disappear when user clicks somewhere outside the form.
Just blur on input elements doesn't work. As soon as you focus away of the input text field to press a submit button, the button disappears  so you cannot press it.
I tried to have a blur method on form, but it didnt seem to work as well.

Thank you for any help.

```
$("#add_wall").click(function(){
    $("#new_wall").animate({
        opacity: 1,
        width: '350'
    }, 500, function() {
        $("#send_button").fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Form looks like

```
<form id="add_wall">
    <input id="new_wall" type="text"  placeholder="Compose new message..." />
    <button id="send_button" style="width:60px; margin-left:5px;" >Post</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting your field itself to have the `.focus()` listener, rather than the wrapping `<form>`.

```
$('#new_wall').focus( function(){
    $("#send_button").fadeIn(400);
});

$('#new_wall').blur( function(){
    $("#send_button").fadeOut(400);
});
```

Blur should work on the field. You can't "unfocus" from something that can't have focus (like an `<a>` or `<input>`).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7p77p/

I don't know what you're trying to do with your field when someone "clicks" on the form (not a solid interaction with the form), so I'm going to ignore that for now. Your field should carry the focus and blur events, however, and your button should respond in kind.

**Edit:** Based on silly oversight on my part.

Then the way I would handle it is this:

```
$('#new_wall').focus( function(){
    $("#send_button").fadeIn(400); // Button shows on focus

    // Create a temporary listener on the body to let someone 'click off'
    $('body').on('click.send_button_showing', function(){
        // User clicks off, button fades out, loses event, and body loses event
        $('#send_button').fadeOut(400);
        $('#send_button').off('click.send_button_click');
        $('body').off('click.send_button_showing');
    });

    // Create temporary event that stops bubbling of the body click 
    // with .stopPropagation()
    $('#send_button').on( 'click.send_button_click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        // Do your send button actions
    });
});
```

Comment: But here is the issue, I want to be able to click on the button. http://jsfiddle.net/5QcQC/

Answer (score 0):

Possibly:

```
$('body').on('click',function(e){
    var targetTagName = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (targetTagName == 'input'){
        $('#send_button').fadeIn(500);
    }
    else if (targetTagName !== 'form'){
        $('#send_button').fadeOut(500);
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UGYtH/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `$.hover` to set/unset a hidden property on the form and then when user clicks anything, you look at that form's property. Looks like this:

```
$('form').hover(function(){ 
      $('form').attr('animate_me',false); 
}, function(){
      $('form').attr('animate_me',true); 
});

$(document).click(function(){
      if($('form').attr('animate_me')===false) return;
      // you can hide your button here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This May be a simliar experience to what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZN4dd/1/

```
var theField = $("#new_wall");
var theButton = $("#send_button");
var theForm = $("#add_wall");
```

//show the form

```
function showForm() {
    theField.stop().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        width: '350'
    }, 500, function() {
        theButton.fadeIn(400);
    });
}
```

//hide the form

```
function hideForm() {
    if (!theField.is(":focus") && !theButton.is(":focus")) {
        theField.stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
            width: '110'
        }, 500, function() {
            theButton.fadeOut(400);
        });
    }
}
theForm.click(showForm).mouseenter(showForm).mouseleave(hideForm);
theField.blur(hideForm)
```

​

I wasn't sure the opacity etc. that you were using by default. This will definitely work then.

Comment: That's really similar things what I want, but I would the field to expand only when I click on it. If I remove .mouseenter(showForm) it will make issues like if user writes something in the input field and then moves mouse outside the form, the button will disappear. But close.